# A solution for using docker and wsl in windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-machine, wsl-2, cloud-native

**When I want to use Docker He doesn't work and give me this error**

An unexpected error was encountered while executing a WSL command. Common causes include access rights issues, which occur after waking the computer or not being connected to your domain/active directory.

Please try shutting WSL down (wsl --shutdown) and/or rebooting your computer. If not sufficient, WSL may need to be reinstalled fully. As a last resort, try to uninstall/reinstall Docker Desktop. If the issue persists please collect diagnostics and submit an issue (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/#diagnose-from-the-terminal).

**What I should to do**

I try to uninstall wsl and docker and  redownload them again but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem is:

1. Go to Task Manager
2. Click on Performance
3. Check if virtualization is disabled; if it is, you must enable it to run Docker.